# How to programmatically detect VB.NET obfuscation?

Tags: vb.net, obfuscation

I am using ConfuserEx to obfuscate my program before release, I want the program to show a warning if it is being run without obfuscation. So as to reduce the chance of a non obfuscated executable being shipped.
So at runtime I want a function which returns true/false depending if obfuscation has been applied.

Comment: Can anyone comment on why you down vote it? It seems like perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: An obfuscator is supposed to emit [assembly:ObfuscateAssemblyAttribute].  If you don't know whether yours does, or you can't find it, then contact the vendor's support for the proper way.

Comment: I am new to reflection, how would I test for assembly:ObfuscateAssemblyAttribute ?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways of doing it.

If the obfuscation process you use is part of the release build and therefore your release build has embedded instructions for the obfuscation part, you could do something like that.

```
AppValidator.Validate()
```

The validation will validate it is a release version or if not, that the application is run for allowed users (dev. team for instance).

I also added a way to validate by commandline calling Myapp.exe validate

However. this does not validated obfuscation per see, it validates the application is in Release mode.

Your obfuscator, if embedded with the release build, should fails if he cannot obfuscate release version or the premise for this validation is not good.

```
Public Class AppValidator
#If DEBUG Then
Private Shared ReadOnly IsDebugVersion As Boolean = True
#Else
private Shared ReadOnly IsDebugVersion As Boolean = False
#End If

Private Shared ReadOnly ISValidUser As Boolean = ValidateDevUser()


''' <summary>
'''     Validate the user is authorized to run the program as 
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Private Shared Function ValidateDevUser() As Boolean
    Try
        ' Custom validation to determine if used in dev. environment such
        'as validating username and domain name or checking agains Dev. Registry key
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function

Public Shared Function Validate() As Boolean
    Dim Args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
    Dim ConsoleValidate As Boolean = Args.Count = 2 AndAlso String.Compare(Args(1), "validate") = 0


    If IsDebugVersion Then
        If ConsoleValidate Then
            Console.WriteLine(Not IsDebugVersion)
            Application.Current.Shutdown()
            Return False
        End If

        If Not ValidateDevUser() Then
            MessageBox.Show("Access Denied")
            Application.Current.Shutdown()
            Return False
        End If

    End If

    Return True
End Function
End Class
```

The first solution is best if you can be sure that build will fails if release version produced and obfuscator steps fails.

If you cannot be sure of that, you can maybe take a look at 
[Obfuscation checker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/#obf-checker), from Red-gate, which is free and has a command-line and do exactly what you seek in a direct approach.

Comment: Thanks, I like your validation logic example. But I did want to check the actual obfuscation and not make the assumption that it was applied correctly during the build process.

Comment: Check the link at the end of my post: Obfucation Checker is a free tool offered by red-gate that allows to do what you seek directly.

Comment: Thanks, I was manually checking by trying to disassemble the exe. The red-gate tool looks useful, although I worry it just a marketing tool for their obfuscation product, thus under-rating the results from other people obfuscation tools. I originally asked for a way to check at run-time, so I can display an error if a non-obfuscated version is being run. Also so the program can log that has no obfuscation. I still don't have a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `ILSpy` and have it run automatically after build with `WM_COPYDATA` API arguments, like so:

https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/blob/master/doc/Command%20Line.txt

Have it navigate to a type name that should be obfuscated; if it fails, you know obfuscation succeeded.